# PHP Websocket SSL Stunnel "bad certificate" with OpenSSL signed certificate

Tags: php, ssl, websocket, openssl, stunnel

I know there are many other questions like this one but after days of tries i have no more ideas for solve the problem.

I'm experiencing Websocket connection for the first time, i need to build a simple Chat and for do this i'm trying PHPWebSocketServer (https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-WebSockets), so i've tested this chat example (https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat) and everything works fine until i use the ws connection (this is a known story).

For the wss i've set up Stunnel with pem signed OpenSSL cert, the service is up, the ports (9040 - 9000) are opened and the websocket server is correctly listening on the port 9000 (php ./server.php), but i can't figure out why in the stunnel.log there is always the "bad certificate" error in each browser client call.

Below there are all the possible useful files and logs.
Start with the Websocket php server files:

server.php

```
<?php
// prevent the server from timing out
set_time_limit(0);

// include the web sockets server script (the server is started at the far bottom of this file)
require 'class.PHPWebSocket.php';

// when a client sends data to the server
function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {
global $Server;
$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

// check if message length is 0
if ($messageLength == 0) {
    $Server->wsClose($clientID);
    return;
}

//The speaker is the only person in the room. Don't let them feel lonely.
if ( sizeof($Server->wsClients) == 1 )
    $Server->wsSend($clientID, "There isn't anyone else in the room, but I'll still listen to you. --Your Trusty Server");
else
    //Send the message to everyone but the person who said it
    foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
        if ( $id != $clientID )
            $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) said \"$message\"");
}

// when a client connects
function wsOnOpen($clientID)
{
global $Server;
$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

$Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has connected." );

//Send a join notice to everyone but the person who joined
foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
    if ( $id != $clientID )
        $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has joined the room.");
}

// when a client closes or lost connection
function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {
global $Server;
$ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

$Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has disconnected." );

//Send a user left notice to everyone in the room
foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
    $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) has left the room.");
}

// start the server
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');
// for other computers to connect, you will probably need to change this to your LAN IP or external IP,
// alternatively use: gethostbyaddr(gethostbyname($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))
$Server->wsStartServer('0.0.0.0', 9000);
?>
```

client-chat.php

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8' />
<style>
    input, textarea {border:1px solid #CCC;margin:0px;padding:0px}

    #body {max-width:800px;margin:auto}
    #log {width:100%;height:400px}
    #message {width:100%;line-height:20px}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="fancywebsocket.js"></script>
<script>
    var Server;

    function log( text ) {
        $log = $('#log');
        //Add text to log
        $log.append(($log.val()?"\n":'')+text);
        //Autoscroll
        $log[0].scrollTop = $log[0].scrollHeight - $log[0].clientHeight;
    }

    function send( text ) {
        Server.send( 'message', text );
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        log('Connecting...');
        Server = new FancyWebSocket('wss://xx.xx.xx.xx:9040');

        $('#message').keypress(function(e) {
            if ( e.keyCode == 13 && this.value ) {
                log( 'You: ' + this.value );
                send( this.value );

                $(this).val('');
            }
        });

        //Let the user know we're connected
        Server.bind('open', function() {
            log( "Connected." );
        });

        //OH NOES! Disconnection occurred.
        Server.bind('close', function( data ) {
            log( "Disconnected." );
        });

        //Log any messages sent from server
        Server.bind('message', function( payload ) {
            log( payload );
        });

        Server.connect();
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='body'>
    <textarea id='log' name='log' readonly='readonly'></textarea><br/>
    <input type='text' id='message' name='message' />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

stunnel.conf

```
cert = /home/myuser/ssl-cert/ssl/stunnel.pem
key = /home/myuser/ssl-cert/mykey.key

chroot = /var/run/stunnel
pid = /stunnel.pid
client = no
fips = no

sslVersion = all
options = NO_SSLv2 ;also commented but same result
options = NO_SSLv3 ;also commented but same result

accept = foobar

socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1

debug = 7
output = /var/log/stunnel/stunnel.log

[stunnel]
accept = 0.0.0.0:9040
connect = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

My OpenSSL signed cert come from ssls (COMODO) CA, as suggested in the stunnel howto i've used the hostname of the server machine as common name, let's call it (mydomain.com), but i've also another OpenSSL cert with the domain name of my website as common name for the https mode (www.mydomain.com), i've used both but the error is still the same.

Anyway, COMODO sent me 4 different files, mydomain_com.crt, COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt, COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt, AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt, and i've sorted them in this exact way into the stunnel.pem file.

stunnel.log (at service start)

```
2015.04.24 17:39:30 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: Snagged 64 random bytes from /dev/urandom
2015.04.24 17:39:30 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: RAND_status claims sufficient entropy for the PRNG
2015.04.24 17:39:30 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: PRNG seeded successfully
2015.04.24 17:39:30 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: Configuration SSL options: 0x03000000
2015.04.24 17:39:30 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: SSL options set: 0x03000004
2015.04.24 17:39:30 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: Certificate: /home/myuser/ssl-cert/ssl/stunnel.pem
2015.04.24 17:39:30 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: Certificate loaded
2015.04.24 17:39:30 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: Key file: /home/myuser/ssl-cert/mykey.key
2015.04.24 17:39:30 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: Private key loaded
2015.04.24 17:39:30 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: SSL context initialized for service stunnel
2015.04.24 17:39:30 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: FIPS mode disabled
2015.04.24 17:39:31 LOG5[13406:139929686013888]: stunnel 4.29 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu with OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
2015.04.24 17:39:31 LOG5[13406:139929686013888]: Threading:PTHREAD SSL:ENGINE,FIPS Sockets:POLL,IPv6 Auth:LIBWRAP
2015.04.24 17:39:31 LOG6[13406:139929686013888]: file ulimit = 1024 (can be changed with 'ulimit -n')
2015.04.24 17:39:31 LOG6[13406:139929686013888]: poll() used - no FD_SETSIZE limit for file descriptors
2015.04.24 17:39:31 LOG5[13406:139929686013888]: 500 clients allowed
2015.04.24 17:39:31 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: FD 10 in non-blocking mode
2015.04.24 17:39:31 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: FD 11 in non-blocking mode
2015.04.24 17:39:31 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: FD 12 in non-blocking mode
2015.04.24 17:39:31 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: SO_REUSEADDR option set on accept socket
2015.04.24 17:39:31 LOG7[13406:139929686013888]: stunnel bound to 0.0.0.0:9040
2015.04.24 17:39:31 LOG7[13412:139929686013888]: Created pid file /stunnel.pid
```

stunnel.log (client wss call)

```
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686013888]: stunnel accepted FD=13 from xx.xx.xx.xx:62481
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: stunnel started
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: FD 13 in non-blocking mode
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: TCP_NODELAY option set on local socket
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: Waiting for a libwrap process
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: Acquired libwrap process #0
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: Releasing libwrap process #0
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: Released libwrap process #0
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: stunnel permitted by libwrap from xx.xx.xx.xx:62481
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG5[13412:139929686116096]: stunnel accepted connection from xx.xx.xx.xx:62481
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL state (accept): before/accept initialization
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 read client hello A
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write server hello A
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write certificate A
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write server done A
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 flush data
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 read client key exchange A
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 read finished A
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write session ticket A
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 write finished A
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL state (accept): SSLv3 flush data
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]:    0 items in the session cache
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]:    0 client connects (SSL_connect())
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]:    0 client connects that finished
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]:    0 client renegotiations requested
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]:    1 server connects (SSL_accept())
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]:    1 server connects that finished
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]:    0 server renegotiations requested
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]:    0 session cache hits
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]:    0 external session cache hits
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]:    0 session cache misses
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]:    0 session cache timeouts
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG6[13412:139929686116096]: SSL accepted: new session negotiated
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG6[13412:139929686116096]: Negotiated ciphers: AES128-SHA SSLv3 Kx=RSA Au=RSA Enc=AES(128) Mac=SHA1
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: FD 14 in non-blocking mode
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG6[13412:139929686116096]: connect_blocking: connecting 127.0.0.1:9000
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: connect_blocking: s_poll_wait 127.0.0.1:9000: waiting 10 seconds
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG5[13412:139929686116096]: connect_blocking: connected 127.0.0.1:9000
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG5[13412:139929686116096]: stunnel connected remote server from 127.0.0.1:50258
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: Remote FD=14 initialized
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: TCP_NODELAY option set on remote socket
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: SSL alert (read): fatal: bad certificate
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG3[13412:139929686116096]: SSL_read: 14094412: error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG5[13412:139929686116096]: Connection reset: 0 bytes sent to SSL, 0 bytes sent to socket
2015.04.24 17:45:10 LOG7[13412:139929686116096]: stunnel finished (0 left)
```

i've also tried the openssl client connection

```
openssl s_client -connect xx.xx.xx.xx:9040
```

and it works!

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i've also tried the openssl client connection ... and it works!

It is not clear what is working: probably the connection and the SSL handshake is working. And if the trust chain is working to you get `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`. But `openssl s_client` does not do any hostname checks, while the browsers do.

> Server = new FancyWebSocket('wss://xx.xx.xx.xx:9040');

This will only work if your certificate is actually for the given IP. But I doubt that you've bought a certificate for a specific IP, because one usually buys a certificate for a hostname. Since you don't access the server by the name contained in the certificate the hostname verification will fail.

Comment: Thank you! Solved! changing the wss://xx.xx.xx.xx:9040 to wss://mydomain.com:9040 is now correctly connected

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, thanks a lot!! I spent more than a week solving this weird issue where my proxy was returning different kind of errors saying that my certificate was bad while everything was set up correctly. I was pulling my hair out after a couple of days :-)